# Laravel Eloquent duplicate query

Tags: laravel, pagination, eloquent

I want to paginate all my articles. 15 of them per page.
Here is the call to paginate: 
`Article::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(15)`

The pagination works fine but the problem is that on each article Laravel makes a query on my users table. 15 articles per page, 15 duplicate queries to my users table.
Here is the image from debugbar:
[image source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7IwV.png)

How can I optimize the pagination and erase all those duplicate queries?

Comment: What relationship do you use between User and Article models?

Comment: In user model I have `public function articles()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Article::class);
    }` and in articles I have `public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using one-to-many relationship between these models, so to solve this problem (which is called `N+1 query problem`), use [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

```
Article::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->with('user')->paginate(15)
```